# Ask about Verb form in this sentence

Tags: verbs

This sentence below is using V-ing in two different ways. It says "population enjoying" and "standing at".

> The number of Internet users expanded nearly fivefold, with the
>   proportion of the world's **population enjoying** Internet access now
>   **standing** at nearly thirty per cent.

I'm so confused about the way this sentence is using V-ing.

Comment: It's a hard sentence to parse.  Try "*... with the proportion of the world's population **(that enjoy Internet access)** standing at nearly 30%*"  Or, taking out all the extras, it becomes:  *The number of users expanded, with the proportion now standing at 30%.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on participles.

Present continuous action:

> She is painting the door.

Present participle describing the skill of painting.

> She is very good at painting.

Present participle describing the result of the act of painting.

> This is a very good piece of painting. It is an excellent piece of art.

> Her painting the door is inconveniencing everyone who needs to get through the hallway.

> Her needing to paint the door during lunch time demonstrates her inconsiderate attitude.

The present participle can be used to turn a verb into a (complex) noun:

> Her {noun} is very noisy

- Nancy's {black dog} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {barking dog} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {dog's barking} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {dog barking} is very annoying. She is annoying everyone by frequently barking like a dog.
- Nancy's {ice-cream habit} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {slurping} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {ice-cream slurping} is very noisy.
- Nancy's {dog barking at night} is now occupying 30% of my sleeping hours. Her dog is annoying.
- Nancy's {dog-barking at night} is now occupying 30% of my sleeping hours. Her {barking like a dog} is preventing me from having proper sleep.

enjoying = participle; turning = present continuous verb:

- The world's {population enjoying internet} is turning me into a 30% nut-case.

There are other forms of participles:

- The recently {promoted} sergeant is getting married.
- The recently {blessed} saints will inherit the earth.
- {Blessed} is the man who sells all that he has to buy the field, to possess the rare pearl he found in the field.
- {Blessed} are the geek, for they shall inherit the world wide web.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. @Blessed Geek, Can i ask your more question : What the verb can be use as the "participles"

Comment: I don't understand your question.